# Preventing Browser Text Input Suggestions

Tags: css, browser, user-interface

I am building my own local search UI element that gives local search suggestions as you type. The problem I am having is that when I focus on the html text input element my browser (Safari, but could happen in other browsers) displays its own text suggestions based on things that I've typed in the past.

My guess is that this is dependent on the ID or Class of the < input > tag. So probably, if I change the input tag class to something obscure, the browser will not have any suggestions to offer. But I wonder if there isn't a more elegant way...

A related issue is about text field highlighting that happens in Safari when you focus on the < input > element. When I am filling up a form on Facebook, I don't see this outline. It would be great to hear if someone knows how to handle those two issues.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Gecko-based browsers support a tag attribute called "autocomplete".  So in your `<form>` tag you would put `<form autocomplete="off">`.

More here:  [How to turn off form autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Some other browsers have support for this as well.  I believe IE will honor this.

Comment: This is what I use, unfortunately it's not "official" AFAIK

Comment: Yeah, as far as I'm aware, there's no universal standard that all browsers implement for this sort of thing.